# Обход всех записей данных в PDO

Tags: php, база-данных, pdo

Как обойти все записи в базе данных с помощью PDO? Следующий код не дает результата
(файл `congfig.php`)

```
<?php
$dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myishop';
$user='root';
$password='';
?>
```

файл `ajaxcategory1.php`

```
require_once('config.php');
$pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$sql='SELECT * FROM monoblocks';
$query=$pdo->prepare($sql);
$result=$query->execute();
while ($example=$result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    $return['querycontent']='<div style="width: 100%; border: 2px solid red"></div>';
};
```

Comment: А причем тут javascript и jquery?

Comment: какое значение вы вкладываете в "не дает результата"?  кстати есть метод fetchAll

Comment: @АлексейШиманский работает с ошибкой

Comment: Это тоже самое что сказать врачу "у меня болит". Подробности нужны

Comment: и что значит обойти все записи? выбрать все записи из бд?

Comment: реально, что за ошибка-то? коннект-то точно устанавливается вообще?..